# TKinter & Python : how to give process name?

Tags: python, tkinter, process, naming

When i run a TKinter program, created with Python 3, in my Linux System Monitor i only see "Python3" as its process name. How can i change that? I would like to see a name which indicates my program.

As a solution i only found https://blog.abhi.host/blog/2010/10/18/changing-process-name-of-python-script/ but i did not try that yet. I guess TKinter provides a more simple way !?

UPDATE
The solution of the link ("Changing process name of python script in linux") does work indeed !
Example code :

```
from ctypes import cdll, byref, create_string_buffer

procname = b'myprogramname\x00'  # Null terminated string

def setProcName(self):
    libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')  # Loading a 3rd party library C
    buff = create_string_buffer(len(procname)+1)  # Note: One larger than the name (man prctl says that)
    buff.value = procname  # Null terminated string as it should be

    libc.prctl(15, byref(buff), 0, 0, 0)
    # Refer to "#define" of "/usr/include/linux/prctl.h" for the mysterious value 16 & arg[3..5] are zero as the man page says.
```

Comment: I think changing the name of a process is a OS dependent thing, so I believe your solution is perfectly fine. I don't think TKinter will provide something for that.

Comment: @toti08 : thanks !  I managed to solve it !  See UPDATE above.